# index.php in Codeigniter install on sub-folder

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I've got a small problem while installing codeigniter on a sub-folder within my project. The problem is that I'am not able to remove the `index.php` from the url. I've got an `.htaccess` file which was working absolutely fine until I installed it inside a sub-folder. The folder structure is as given below:

`test_project/myapp`
myapp - codeigniter installation folder.

CodeIgniter Config:
base url : "http://localhost/test_project/myapp/"

My `.htaccess` file contains the following:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /myapp
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

The above `.htaccess` file works perfectly if I shift my `codeigniter` installation to the `test_project`.I've placed the `.htaccess` within my sub-folder(myapp) where the `index.php` resides.

I have installed this on a `WAMP` server and am using `codeigniter 2.1.2`

Thanks

Comment: Does the myapp folder contain both the system and application directories? If not, where is the system directory?

Comment: yes..it contains both..the system as well as the application directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove or comment these lines:

```
RewriteBase /myapp
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

The reasoning is that the proceeding 3 lines in your .htaccess are relative and should work no matter what directory you decide to put your application in.